# Why is the limit not $\ln(x)$?

Tags: calculus, limits

For all $a \neq 1$ we have

$$\int x^{-a}dx=\frac{x^{1-a}}{1-a}$$ and for $a =1$ we have $\int \frac{1}{x}dx=\ln(x) $.
Now, when we try to take the limit

$$\lim_{a\to 1}  \frac{x^{1-a}}{1-a} = \lim_{a\to 0}  \frac{x^{a}}{a} = \pm \infty.$$
Why do we get that limit and not something "suitable" to $\ln(x)$?

Comment: Why should we? Also note that actually
$$\int \frac1x \ \mathrm dx = \ln |x| \color{grey}{ + C}$$

Comment: I'm pretty sure this has been asked before. But finding that question is a different matter...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because 
$$\lim_{a\to 1}\int x^{-a}dx\neq \int\lim_{a\to 1}x^{-a}dx.$$

Comment: I don't think this answer makes any sense at all. The indefinite integral is only defined up to an additive constant, so taking limits isn't well-defined!

Comment: But it's what the OP wanted to do...

Answer (score 2):

You have forgotten the all-important indefinite constant of integration. So your equation "$\int x^{-a}dx=\frac{x^{1-a}}{1-a}$" is wrong. Writing the equation instead as a definite integral $$\int_1^x t^{-a}\,\mathrm dt=\frac{x^{1-a}-1}{1-a}\;\;\;(a\neq1,\,x>0),$$ you now have the right starting point for taking the limit $a\rightarrow 1$.

Comment: sorry, in this cas, you are right.